# C# and C++ dll - marshalling strings

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling

I made a test application to pass a C# string to a C++ DLL to return its changed value.

Examples taken from MSDN:

[Marshaling Data with Platform Invoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/marshaling-data-with-platform-invoke)

[Strings Sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/e765dyyy(v=vs.100))

Part of the class for defining `DllImport`:

```cs
public class LibWrap
{
    [DllImport(
        "PInvokeLib.dll",
        EntryPoint = "TestStringAsResult",
        ExactSpelling = true,
        CharSet = CharSet.Ansi,
        SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern string TestStringAsResult(string value);
}
```

DLL function call:

```cs
const string s = "My string !!!";
var str = LibWrap.TestStringAsResult(s);
Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "String returned: {0}", str);
// String returned: My string !!!AAA or String returned: My string !!!+counter value
```

In the DLL code, I will work with the string and return its changed value:

```cpp
// int counter = 0;
PINVOKELIB_API char* TestStringAsResult(char* value)
{
    const size_t alloc_size = 64;
    const auto result = static_cast<char*>(CoTaskMemAlloc(alloc_size));
    // counter++;
    std::string work_str = value;
    work_str += "AAA";
    //work_str += std::to_string(counter);
    StringCchCopyA(result, alloc_size, const_cast<char*>(work_str.c_str()));
    return result;
}
```

Then I did a loop 10 times, for example in C# code:

```cs
const string s = "My string !!!";
var str = LibWrap.TestStringAsResult(s);
Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "String returned: {0}", str);
```

And got the result from `"My string !!! 1"` to `"My string !!! 10"`

This suggests that the DLL is statically loaded into the C# application process - do I understand this correctly?

It turns out the memory is allocated 10 times in the DLL for the result?

Do I need to use `CoTaskMemFree()` or not? And if it is needed - how do I call it on the C# side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer in the book Adam Nathan
`.NET and COM: The Complete Interoperability Guide`
on page 791 in chapter 18

friend gave me [this link](https://books.google.ru/books?id=x2OIPSyFLBcC&pg=PT1029&lpg=PT1029&dq=cotaskmemfree%20pinvoke&source=bl&ots=_rzIYO4Rm_&sig=ACfU3U27x4nOJXmIRgsYvbjMaQ2m-JtMcw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiusdq2ir3pAhXoxcQBHU1rD9UQ6AEwBHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=cotaskmemfree%20pinvoke&f=false)

> Another case that requires the use of IntPtr occurs when a function
>   allocates memory and expects the caller to free the memory. This is
>   fairly rare in Win32 APIs, because most operate on a caller-allocated
>   buffer (as in the examples that use StringBuilder). When a PInvoke
>   signature returns a string (either via a return type or a by-reference
>   parameter), the Interop Marshaler internally copies the contents of
>   the unmanaged string to a .NET string, **then calls CoTaskMemFree (the
>   unmanaged equivalent of Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem) to free the unmanaged
>   string**. This is a problem, however, if the unmanaged string was not
>   allocated with **CoTaskMemAlloc**!